# VSCode C++ automatically comment out error lines in class header file on removing some member variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Given `header.h` with:

```
class foo_{
    int getint() const {return val;}
private:
    int val;
}
```

If I comment out as: `//int val;`, the editor correctly shows that line `int getint()...` has the error `identifier "val" is undefined`.

I have many such variables that I would like to comment out. Now, I am having to navigate to each of the member functions that reference these variables and individually comment these out. Is there a way to automate this process via some keystrokes/macros/multicommand that should roughly:

(a)navigate to each line with error in current file, in turn, and

(b)comment that line.

---

ETA: Ideally, I only want to navigate to each line within the current class definition that shows an error, but if that is not possible, then (a) above where one goes through each line with error in the current file is fine.

Comment: what if some other code calls `getint` ? That should be commented out as well?

Comment: No, it should apply automatically only to current file. In other places/files, I would want to look through and see how this variables is used.

Comment: You can use #ifdef _SOMETHING_ #else #endif and this way you can hide or make visible a line or a block of code

Comment: @CppProgrammer23 indeed. but that won't help here. Do you propose a #ifdef #endif block for each member function?

Comment: I think yes, you don't have any other choice